# Flow - Removing Get Records Element From Within Loop

Tags: visual-workflow

I recently built a Record-Triggered Flow on the Account object to update a field on related Opportunities. Today I was notified System Limits were reached for the Org, related to this Flow.

```
You or your organization has exceeded the maximum limit for this feature.
```

After doing some research, it looks like Get Records should not be used within a Loop. However, I am not sure why. The loop is only iterating 6-8 times max, as there are only so many related Opportunities per account, and when I debug records individually I am not close to any limits.

Here are the steps in the logic:

1. I get all related opportunity records
2. I loop through the opportunity records
3. I check the 'Selling Season' field on each record
4. Based on the 'Selling Season', I assign a value, add to collection variable, and update the record.

[image]

My questions are the following:

Is there an 'easy' way to rectify this, and if not, can I add more conditions to prevent Limits from being reached?

Comment: (1) Is this flow being executed for a batch of records - there's a limit on the number of flow elements per transaction. (2) Winter 23 added the IN operator for Get Records which is designed to avoid Get Records in loops

Comment: 1. No. It is only being used on 1 record per time. 2 Thank you for that. I'll look into the IN operator

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have too many issues here so the answer is "we cannot provide a viable solution".

1. "I get all related Opportunity records"
   Yet I see multiple Get Opportunity Records in the decision paths.
2. "It looks like Get Records should not be used within a Loop"
   Absolutely not. Only as a last resort under some circumstances such as when the record is not directly related via a lookup but through something like a text field.

Given that I see two record lookups to the same object in many of the decision paths that's a red flag right there. If that is required, again bad, definitely only 1 to same object.

Please look at some of the flow bulkification blogs on the Internet to see how to modify this and then if there is still a question after making those changes, create another post.